# split int col in Teradata

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I was trying to split int column in Teradata but its showing error

> *** Failure 9134 Unsupported type detected.

```
SELECT col1,strtok(col2,0 ,1) FROM table;
```

Comment: What are your rules for *split int column*, based on which split character? Based on your example you want to split on zeroes? Crazy

Comment: Show some sample data and desired results.  Is `col2` actually defined as integer? STRTOK only works on char/varchar...